# Executing a Genetic Programming tree

Tags: genetic-programming

I am running GP algorithm using ECJ 26 during that I use describe() function to test the tree, however, currently I need to store and execute the tree outside ECJ framework.

Please, could you let me know if it is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to executing a tree (like an [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)) would be traversing the tree using the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and taking actions based on the current node and the current state of the executor (your "virtual machine"). This is how the so called *tree walk interpreters* work (a typical example is the Ruby interpreter prior to v1.9).

This is for sure a very generic answer, but hopefully it'll give you some ideas.